# Method becomes nil after an ajax response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code does the following: If the user, **voted up** show him a *delete vote* form and a *vote down form*. If the user **voted down**, show him a *vote up form* and the *delete vote form*. Otherwise just show the *vote up and vote down form* (I omitted some of the code so the question doesn't get too long).

[image]

(scenario: user voted down):

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @replies = @post.replies.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @reply = @post.replies.build
    @vote = Vote.new
    store_location
  end
```

**votes_controller.rb:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :signed_in_user

 def create
    @votable = find_votable

    # Destroy the vote first in case the user already voted
    if already_voted?
      @vote = @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
      @vote.destroy
    end

    @vote = @votable.votes.build(params[:vote])
    @vote.user_id = current_user.id
    @votable.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_back }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @votable = find_votable

    @vote = @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    @vote.destroy
    @votable.reload

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_back }
      format.js
    end
  end


  private

    def find_votable
      params.each do |name, value|
        if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
          return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
        end
      end
      nil
    end

    def already_voted?
      @votable.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end
end
```

**posts/vote_form**

```
<div class="vote-form">
  <% if @post.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id) %>
    <% if @post.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).polarity == -1 %>
      <%= form_for ([@post, @vote]), remote: true do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :polarity, value: 1 %>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "btn btn-small vote" do %>
            <i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i> Vote up
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= form_for ([@post, @post.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)]),
                                                           method: :delete,
                                                           remote: true do |f| %>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "btn btn-small btn-primary unvote" do %>
            <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> Vote down
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

**votes/create.js:**

```
$('#<%= @votable.class.name.downcase %>-<%= @votable.id %> .vote-form').html(
  "<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/delete_vote')) %>"
);
```

**shared/_delete_vote.html.erb:**

```
<% if @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).polarity == -1 %>
  <%= form_for ([@votable, @votable.votes.new]), remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "vote-down btn btn-small" do %>
        <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> Vote up
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_for ([@votable, @vote]), method: :delete, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "vote-up btn btn-small btn-primary" do %>
        <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> Vote down
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, now everything works fine, except that I get this error when I click *vote down*, and then *vote up* right after (without refreshing the page):

> ```
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `polarity' for nil:NilClass):
>     1: <% if @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).polarity == 1 %>
>     2:   <%= form_for ([@votable, @vote]), method: :delete, remote: true do |f| %>
> ```

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I realized that the line in the error message is the problem (not `@votable`):

```
<% if @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).polarity == 1 %>
```

Strange, I thought it was the same as

```
<% if @post.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).polarity == 1 %>
```

Comment: Are you passing the CSRF token in the ajax call?

Comment: @peterpan I'm not sure what's that, so maybe I'm not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
def destroy
  @votable = find_votable

  @vote = @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  @vote.destroy
  @votable.reload

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

You destroy the vote for current user, so it can not be found inside view:

```
@votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).polarity
```

That's why polarity is called on nil. You should reword the logic of your vote manipulations.

#### EDIT:

As the easiest solution, you may replace

```
if @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).polarity == -1
```

with

```
if @votable.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).blank?
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you five me an example or a better logic?

Comment: I think you are right (right now I'm only testing the create action), but as you can see in the create action, `@vote` is immediately defined right after it is destroyed?

Comment: May you replace ```@vote = @votable.votes.build(params[:vote])
    @vote.user_id = current_user.id
    @votable.save``` with ```@vote = @votable.votes.create(params[:vote].merge(user: current_user))```?

Comment: Also you may need to execute @votable.reload as far as I have no idea about it's logic.

Comment: I can't do that. I get this: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user):`

Comment: You should change attr_accessible inside your ```Vote``` model. I'll leave the rest up to you, because this is turning into one of these "please do my work for me" questions.